# Run plugin handler continuously

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I currently have a Eclipse plugin that highlights Instance variables in a Java class. The command handler is invoked when a menu option is clicked. How can I change it so that instead of clicking the menu option, I can mark the instance variables continuously as the users type? (Just like errors are marked automatically when user types?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extend the `org.eclipse.jdt.core.compilationParticipant` extension point and override the `reconcile` method.  This will get your code called whenever a reconcile operation occurs. It will provide you an AST (possibly with bindings already resolved).

With this, you are expected to add extra markers and annotations to the file through the `ReconcileContext` instance passed in to the method.  Presumably, your plugin is implemented so that instance variables are highlighted using markers and if so, this would fit in nicely with your implementation.

Comment: Thanks Andrew, that did the trick. For other users info, we also need to override `isActive` method to return true inorder to run the CompilationParticipant